# Get resource image by name into custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a custom cursor adapter and I'd like to put an image into a ImageView in a ListView.

My code is:

```
public class CustomImageListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public CustomImageListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // get the ImageView Resource
    ImageView fieldImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fieldImage);
    // set the image for the ImageView
    flagImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageName);
    }

  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_images, parent, false);
  }
}
```

This is all OK but I would like to get the name of image from database (cursor).
I tried with

```
String mDrawableName = "myImageName";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

But return error: "The method getResources() is undefined for the type CustomImageListAdapter"

Comment: If you wanna get from Cursor why you don't call `cursor.getString` instead. And where is your image stored?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only do a `getResources()` call on a Context object. Since the `CursorAdapter`'s constructor takes such a reference, simply create a class member that keeps track of it so that you can use it in (presumably) `bindView(...)`. You'll probably need it for `getPackageName()` too.

```
private Context mContext;

public CustomImageListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

// Other code ...

// Now call getResources() on the Context reference (and getPackageName())
String mDrawableName = "myImageName";
int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thank to "MH." for the solution. (also to "MisterSquonk")

Comment: Why can you use getResources() without appending the context inside an Activity? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo: Because [`Activity` (indirectly) extends from `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). However, there is nothing preventing you from writing `this.getResources()`, which is exactly the same thing, but explicitly includes the object it is called on (where `this` is a reference to the instance of the `Activity`, and thus `Context`).